# Why does the plot of conditional means (conditional mode) or random effects look like this?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am fitting a random effects model with `glmer` from `lme4` in R. The model looks OK to me.

[image]

My understanding is that the random effects come from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.632 (see above). So I was expecting the distribution of conditional means (or conditional modes, obtained by using `getME(modelfit, 'b')`) should more or less follow a bell curve. 
However, when I plot the histogram of the conditional means, I found it very strangel it looks like 2 separate distributions  separated by 0. The plot is here:

[image]

The corresponding Q-Q plot of the conditional modes:
[image]

Does anyone know what this means? Is there some strong confounder? Or can it just behave like this?

Comment: Please post image somewhere that is not behind a password. I will edit it in. If I understand your question and the matter at hand correctly, random effects are assumed to come from a normal distribution. That of course doesn't mean that individual estimated values will come from that distribution. That depends on your data.

Comment: I am so sorry that you cannot see the plot, here is another link: https://github.com/rikku1983/Mixed-model/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-17%20at%208.42.31%20AM.png          And the summary of the fit is here: https://github.com/rikku1983/Mixed-model/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-17%20at%209.13.22%20AM.png

Comment: @LiSun you can copy and paste the **text** of the summary into your answer

Comment: Yes but that is really ugly though, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@RomanLustrik is correct to distinguish between the underlying *assumption* of Normality of the conditional mode and the estimates of the conditional modes themselves. The estimates need not be Normal; see `?qqmath.ranef.mer` for diagnostic plots of the distribution of the conditional modes.  If the distribution of your conditional modes is far from Normal, then you may indeed have a problem. Unfortunately, relaxing the assumption of Normality makes the modeling somewhat harder.  You might, for example, be able to use a latent mixture model where you assume that the conditional modes are drawn from a mixture of two Normals - but I don't know offhand of an R package that implements this; if I were going to do it I would probably implement it using a toolbox like JAGS or Stan.

Before you go that direction, it's important to note that the characteristics of your data (approximately 2 Bernoulli observations per group) are such that the default Laplace approximation is expected to be **very** bad.  Try `nAGQ=10` (or even higher); it will slow your fitting considerably, but may improve the results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I tried to plot the qqplot of conditional modes it looks like this .    https://github.com/rikku1983/Mixed-model/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-18%20at%209.28.13%20AM.png

Comment: And I am still confused that if the estimates need not come from a normal distribution, why are we plotting the qqplot? I still think the qqplot is talking about the same thing as my histogram does. Furthermore, can we think that the conditional modes are just like residuals on the subjects level? So can we diagnose them as we do to residuals in ordinary linear model?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, the conditional modes are analogous to residuals at the subject level, so the various diagnostics (heteroscedasticity, Normality, etc.) are all relevant.  The Q-Q plot does indeed show the same information as the histogram, but it can be easier to see subtle differences from Normality (not that these are subtle differences).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @BenBolker for your help. I am writing what I finally concluded according to my trials and experiences, not exactly a answer buy just want to summarize a little bit.
1. Conditional means are predicts of normal random variables of the random effects. Histograms and QQplot of all conditional means from a specific data can basically be anything, actually in most realistic cases, it will not follow a bell curve. This totally depends on your data. Like in the example I posted above, we saw the two modes histogram because the fix effects are actually not helping a lot to predict, so random effects are 'dragged' into two modes to help the model reach optimal fit. To understand this, see https://github.com/rikku1983/Mixed-model/blob/master/diagnostic1.png. In this plot, x axis are values of on link level from only fixed effects, only random effects (conditional modes, because I have only one random effects) and both. The numbers in the plots are predictive power.
2. This leads to a natural question: does distribution of conditional modes need to follow a bell curve to satisfy assumptions? I don't think so because this is due to your data, in other words, if your data is not a good representation of a the population, even the model is close to truth, the conditional modes would not follow a normal distribution like the population.
3. This leads to a more general question of how should we diagnosing our generalized mixed model, test assumptions of normality and independence between and among random components? I did search on google but still have not found anything I think is really helpful. Any suggestions are welcome.

Again, all above is not guaranteed to be right. Just bring my understanding up for discuss if it is worthy it.

Comment: It's better to add figures in the question/answer than add a links since links get lost.